# Excel EOMONTH date function

Tags: excel

I am trying to use EOMONTH in excel, but I cannot make it work... It i not recognising my date as a date.

I am using excel for mac (ver16.45), in column I type for example 01.01.2020, or 01/01/2020 it always formats as 1.1.20. When I try to change formatting I have asterisk for default date as in my system as *14.3.12 and I leave it like that... than when I use =EOMONTH(C1,0)...

I am getting error ("Not trying to type a formula?
When the first character is an equal ("=") or minus ("-") sign, Excel thinks it's a formula")

I know that for EOMONTH excel need to recognise data as a date, and that it needs to be in format of the system... but for me is simply not working...

I don't know is it mac maybe, or what can be...

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly your separator is the semicolon. If so, try `=EOMONTH(C1;0)`

Comment: Yes... this worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could upload a copy of your workbook, or at least a screenshot of your scenario, so I can get a full understanding of your request. Based on your initial comment, can you replicate my screenshot and let me know if it works?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did the same as you posted, in my excel if I type 01/31/20 it was automatically converting to 31.1.20, but my problem was as mentioned above in separator.. I have to use semicolon as separator.

Comment: Strange. I just tried it on my Mac as well, but was unable to replicate your issue. I am glad you got it figured out. I found these two resources for line separators in Excel 2016 for Mac -in case you want to reconfigure https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/line-separator-comma-semicolon-in-excel-2016-for/7db1b1a0-0300-44ba-ab9b-35d1c40159c6